# ADB install on Pixel 3 is old version of an app

Tags: android, installation, adb

I'm trying to make sure a particular test device (Pixel 3) will install a new version of an apk but whatever I do it seems to be running an older version.

Tried so far:

- `adb uninstall <app_name>`
- `adb install -r <app_name>`
- Manually clearing it's cached data and uninstalling on device
- Restarting device between uninstall and reinstalls

No matter what I do the app appears to be the previously installed version. I'd think I was crazy but I've had issues with the auto-backup on Pixel devices hiding logs, restoring preferences & cache data before.

Any suggestions on how I can 100% force a purge of all the data to do with this apk so I'm guaranteed a fresh install?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a property in your manifest `allowBackup=false` and make sure your instant run is disabled.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that may be it. Which I should have known as I added that to our app........and another developer has since removed it.

Answer (score 0):

For manually uninstalling the app, try:

```
adb shell pm uninstall <app_package_name>
```

If the app is installed, this will say success. If the app is not installed, you usually get an error message.

For installing the app, try with out the "-r" parameter:

```
adb install <app_package_name>
```

Note that installing with the "-r" parameter is for an app update, and thus if you already have the app installed, and do not have a newer app build version (as declared in build.gradle) then it will keep the current version. With just adb install you will see a message if the app already exists.

To check if the app is installed, you can look for the app package name on the device with:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

If you are installing via AndroidStudio, try turning off instant run options by going to Preference and searching for instant run, and having enabled unchecked. Cleaning build, maybe even an invalidate and re-sync caches and try again.

Comment: Even uninstalling with this method does not seem to fix the issue described in the question.